# When using delegatecall, data in parameters of type uint[] are left-shifted by 8 bits

Tags: abi, delegatecall

```
progma solidity ^0.4.15;
contract Callee 
{
    uint public result_;

    function foo (uint _length, uint[] _nums) public returns (uint)
    {    
        result_ = 0;
        for ( uint i = 0; i < _length; ++i)
             result_ += _nums[i];
        return result_;
    }
}

contract Caller
{
    uint public result_;
    address public callee_ = <Address of deployed Callee>;

    function Call (uint[] _nums) public returns (bool)
    {    return callee_.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("foo(uint256,uint256[])")), _nums.length, _nums); }
}
```

These are contracts I have defined. Deploy `Callee` first, then give its address to `Caller` contract, then invoke the `Call` function with parameter `[1]`, however the `result_` value is 256 after calling.
I tested several data, and find out that each data in the `uint256[]` param is left-shifted by 8 bits. But param 1, which has type uint256, is not shifted.

I want to know why.

Answer (score 1):

This is really interesting.  It looks like the Solidity compiler is not correctly marshalling the arguments for the delegate call. In particular, `nums_` is a dynamic type, but it is not being treated as such.

Let's say that your input is `[42]`.  The call data produced by your code as it stands is

```
2fbe983a                                                         // Function selector
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 // _nums.length
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a // _nums
```

This is actually incorrect as `_nums` is a dynamic datatype as per the [ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI), and `foo()` expects it to be encoded as such - when `foo` decodes this it will get junk: this case actually fails to run at all.  In your case, the input `[1]` is interpreted to mean that the `_nums` array is at position `0x01` in the calldata, so its length is interpreted as `0x100` and its contents as `0x100` followed by 255 zeros. Hence your result.

The calldata ought to look like this:

```
2fbe983a                                                         // Function selector
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 // _nums.length
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040 // Pointer to _nums array
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 // Length of _nums array (_nums.length)
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a // _nums array contents
```

You can work around this in your code as follows:

```
return callee_.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("foo(uint256,uint256[])")), _nums.length, 0x40, _nums.length, _nums);
```

This inserts the missing structure for the dynamic data.  Now you can call it with, say, `[1,2,3,4,5]` and get the answer `15` (tested).

Comment: You're welcome. When I get a moment I'll look into reporting this as an issue in Solidity (and checking to see if it really is a bug, or expected behaviour). When you are satisfied with the answer it's good practice to mark it "accepted" for the benefit of others.

Comment: It turns out that this is already raised [as an issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2269) on the Solidity github. It's been classified as a "documentation issue", and my proposed workaround is the correct way to go.